# Openstack change IP address of compute node, controller will not change

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Ran into some trouble... when installing more compute nodes, I acidentially left the local_ip located in /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini the same for the additional compute nodes. Now a

```
openstack hypervisor list
```

shows:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| ID | Hypervisor Hostname | Hypervisor Type | Host IP      | State |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
|  1 | ccloud1             | QEMU            | 10.131.39.41 | up    |
|  2 | ccloud2             | QEMU            | 10.131.39.40 | up    |
|  3 | ccloud3             | QEMU            | 10.131.39.40 | up    |
|  5 | ccloud4             | QEMU            | 10.131.39.40 | up    |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
```

I have taken the following action to try to fix this, but it does not work,
using ccloud4 as an example:

On controller:

```
openstack compute service set --disable ccloud4 nova-compute
```

On ccloud4:

```
systemctl stop nova-compute
systemctl stop neutron-linuxbridge-agent
```

On controller:

```
openstack compute service list
# above is to get ID, it was 11
openstack compute service delete 11
openstack network agent list
# it still shows up there, lets delete it by UUID
openstack network agent delete 433153bd-896d-45c3-b6ae-1ac5cf9cf6b3
```

At this point a openstack hypervisor list and openstack network agent list show it is gone, so far so good, lets add it back in:

On ccloud4:

```
systemctl start nova-compute
systemctl start neutron-linuxbridge-agent
```

On controller:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
openstack compute service list
openstack network agent list
openstack hypervisor list
```

Annnnd, it is still there listed at IP address 10.131.39.40. Not sure how to delete and then add back ccloud2,3,4 and have them at a new IP address.

Just to be clear, the actual IP address of ccloud2,3,4 were always correct (10.131.39.42,43,44, respectively), it was only in the /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini file that it was in error.

I have also [performed these steps](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/120385/how-to-remove-compute-node/) with no luck.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So, as it turns out, I had copied the nova.conf also from ccloud1 to the others.

I edited it, but forgot the one line my_ip=10.131.39.40, so the controller node was always picking them up as 10.131.39.40 instead of their IP address. Interestingly, it is a quick fix:

On controller:

```
openstack compute service list
openstack compute service delete ID
```

Then mod the /etc/nova/nova.conf file on the compute node and then do:

```
systemctl restart nova-compute
systemctl restart neutron-linuxbridge-agent
```

Back on the controller, do:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
```

Verify:

```
openstack hypervisor list
```

Done.